# Standard pixel format Linux VA-API

Tags: graphics, vaapi

Is there a standard (or de facto standard) pixel format in the va api that both software and drivers needs to implement as a minimum?

I currently trying to debug va-api implementation between software that seems to hard code it to RGBX_8888/XRGB and driver that seems to only accept YUV_420_BIPLANAR/NV12. This will obviously not work. So, what is the "de facto standard" or "expectations"? I don't want to write "requirements" because it is after all open source projects and not a commercial product, but both sides are projects coming from large major companies so I do expect some kind of platform standard, minimum implementation so things can work or it would not be much use of a standard va-api. Should the driver support more than one pixel format or should the software? And if so which one?